Proof of closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k-1){(n-1)}^{n-k-1}{n \choose k}$
I experimented around with sum
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\left(k - 1\right)
\left(n - 1\right)^{n - k - 1}{n \choose k}
$$
and conjectured that it is equal to
$\left(n - 1\right)^{n - 1} - 1$ which, according to $\tt Wolfram Alpha$, it is.

But I cannot find a proof for this equivalency.
My question is how would one prove this ?.
If one changes the bounds to $k = 0$ to $n$ then the sum becomes $0$ if that does anything.


Let's write $x=n-1$ for the (base) term inside the sum.
Then the sum can be written as
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k-1)x^{n-k-1} \binom{n}{k}
= x^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k-1) x^{-k} \binom{n}{k}
= x^{n-1} \left(-(n-1)x^{-n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1) (x^{-1})^k \binom{n}{k}\right)
= x^{n-1} \left(-(n-1)x^{-n} + \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k (x^{-1})^k \binom{n}{k}\right) - \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} (x^{-1})^k \binom{n}{k} \right) + 1  \right)
= x^{n-1} \left(-(n-1)x^{-n} + nx^{-1}(x^{-1}+1)^{n-1} - (x^{-1}+1)^n + 1 \right)
$$
By the binomial formula $(1+y)^n = \sum_{j=0}^n y^j \binom{n}{j}$ and its derived and multiplied by $y$ version $ny(1+y)^{n-1} = \sum_{j=1}^n j y^j \binom{n}{j}$. (Where we set $y=x^{-1}$.)
This simplifies to
$$
S = (n-1)x^{-1}(-1+(1+x)^{n-1}) - (1+x)^{n-1} + x^{n-1}
$$
and plugging in $x=n-1$ gives
$$
S = -1+n^{n-1}-n^{n-1} + (n-1)^{n-1} = (n-1)^{n-1} - 1.
$$

When you first factor out the $x^{n-1}$, your first term $-(1-n)x^{-n}$ should be $-(n-1)x^{-n}$ and then the final expression will be correct.

@RobPratt Thanks, fixed it.

This question can be solved using the fact that $$\sum_{r=0}^n{n \choose r}\,{x^r}=(1+x)^n$$
$$\sum_{r=0}^n{n \choose r}\,x^{r-1}=\frac{(1+x)^n}{x}$$
Now diffrentiating both sides-
$$\sum_{r=0}^n{n \choose r}\,(r-1)\,x^{r-2}=\frac{nx(1+x)^{n-1}-(1+x)^{n}}{x^2}$$
$$\sum_{r=2}^n{n \choose r}\,(r-1)\,x^{r-2}=\frac{nx(1+x)^{n-1}-(1+x)^{n}+1}{x^2}$$
Now multiply by $x^2$ and then replacing $x$ with its reciprocal,then multiplying by $x^{n-1}$ and putting $x=n-1$ gives the required sum
